# User friendly array definition macro

Tags: loops, comma-separated-list, arrayjob

I am working on a custom documentclass where there may be one or multiple authors in a document. Normally, one would simply specify `\author{}` and call some additional macros to set some special values, for example `\email{}` (a command defined in the class code).

Then, in the `\maketitle` macro defined in the class, I just do

```
{\Large\@author \texttt{<\@email>}}
```

This works well, but now I would like to extend the class’s functionality by letting users specify multiple authors and multiple emails (of course, their number should be the same). Here is a concept:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\title{Glorious ducks}
\authors{{John Smith}{Jane Smith}{George Hastings}}
\emails{{john.smith@domain.tld}{jane.smith@domain.tld}{george.hastings@something.net}}
```

Then, `\maketitle` would contain something like this (pseudocode):

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\for \i in \len\@authors {
    \@authors{i} & \@emails{i} \\
}
```

**I do not need the syntax to be like in the example, it was just to show the concept.**

---

One possible solution I found was using the `arrayjobx` package. I can supply a macro such as this in the class:

```
\newcommand\authors[1]{\newarray\@Authors\readarray{@Authors}{#1}}
```

then the user can do

```
\authors{John Smith & Jane Smith & George Hastings}
```

and `\maketitle` could somehow iterate over this array… but I don’t see a way in `arrayjobx` to get the length of the array, which renders this solution pretty much useless. I do not want to specify an array as well as it’s length as a user.

**How would you solve this problem?** I do not insist on using `arrayjobx`, a more ‘elegant’ (La)TeX solution is most welcome, if possible. Thank you.

To sum it up:

- users may either specify `\author` and `\email` to get a document with a single author
- or `\authors` and `\emails` to get a document with multiple authors that are listed in a tabular environment

Comment: why separate `\authors` command rather than just allow more than one `\author` ? also I think it is easier for the author if you specify each email with each auther rather than two separate lists which need to match up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point, I thought about using `\author` multiple times. Your argument about including the emails with the author names is also valid, but do you mean simply like `\author{John Smith <john.smith@domain.tld>}`? I would like the email addresses in monospace, so this way an author would have to add that formatting themselves: `\author{John Smith \texttt<john.smith@domain.tld>}`

Comment: no I just meant specify it with the author either \auther then \email as I just posted or as an optional argument  `\author[email]{name}` Note you almost never need an indexed array syntax or an explicit loop in these things you just build up a list and execute it.

Comment: Ah, how silly of me. Fair enough, that syntax is much better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly I wouldn't use such a syntax. I would prefer something like `\author{xxx \and xxx \and xxx}` but adding also emails would be non trivial. With your desired syntax the email list must be given in the same order as the author's list, which I find too complicated.

You can look into different classes to see how they handle things. This could be a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newif\if@email
\@emailfalse
\def\@author{}
\def\@@author{\gdef\@@author{\\[1ex]}}
\def\author#1{\@emailfalse\g@addto@macro\@author{\@@author#1}}
\def\email#1{\if@email\g@addto@macro\@author{\\&#1}\else\g@addto@macro\@author{&#1}\@emailtrue\fi}

\def\maketitle{\begin{tabular}{ll}\@author\end{tabular}}

\makeatother

\author{Me Myself}
\email{me@myself.com}
\email{me.again@myself.com}

\author{Someone Else}
\email{someone@elses.mail}

\author{Yet Another}
\email{yet.another@service1.com}
\email{y.another@service2.com}

\author{Last One}
\email{last@one.mail}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or something similar without creating a new `\if` but redefining an `\@emailsep` at every call of `\author`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\LoadClass{article}
\def\@author{}
\def\@authorsep{\gdef\@authorsep{\\[1ex]}}

\def\author#1{%
   \g@addto@macro\@author{%
      \@authorsep#1%
      \gdef\@emailsep{&\gdef\@emailsep{\\&}}%
   }%
}
\def\email#1{\g@addto@macro\@author{\@emailsep\texttt{#1}}}

\def\maketitle{%
   \begin{center}
   \large\bfseries\@title
   \end{center}
   \noindent
   \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
   \@author
   \end{tabular}%
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{myclass}

\title{Great Work}

\author{Me Myself}
\email{me@myself.com}
\email{me.again@myself.com}

\author{Someone Else}
\email{someone@elses.mail}

\author{Yet Another}
\email{yet.another@service1.com}
\email{y.another@service2.com}

\author{Last One}
\email{last@one.mail}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks fantastic, thank you! I agree that this syntax is a lot cleaner. I just thought it would be very hard to handle multiple `\author`s. I will see if I can decipher what this code does :-)

Comment: +1 you just beat me to it, I nearly didn't post mine once I saw this  but as i'd done it and the OP might like a couple of examples, I left it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Separate gathering information from typesetting:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_bpclass_author_seq
\seq_new:N \g_bpclass_email_seq

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bpclass_author_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\email}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bpclass_email_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
    \g_bpclass_author_seq
    \g_bpclass_email_seq
    \bpclass_print_author:nn
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bpclass_print_author:nn
 {
  #1 % author name 
  &
  \ttfamily #2 % email
  \\[2ex]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\author{John Smith}
\email{john.smith@domain.tld}

\author{Jane Smith}
\email{jane.smith@domain.tld}

\author{George Hastings}
\email{george.hastings@something.net}

\printauthors

\end{document}
```

The authors' names and emails are gathered in sequences and then used to make a `tabular`; but you can reuse the items in several other ways.

Of course this is only a skeleton, there are so many variations and there's possibly to accommodate affiliations and maybe multiple email addresses.

Here's another possibility, taking care of the affiliation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_bpclass_author_seq
\seq_new:N \g_bpclass_affiliation_seq
\seq_new:N \g_bpclass_email_seq

\RenewDocumentCommand{\author}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bpclass_author_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\affiliation}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bpclass_affiliation_seq { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\email}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_bpclass_email_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthors}{}
 {
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \g_bpclass_author_seq \bpclass_print_author:nn
  \end{minipage}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bpclass_print_author:nn
 {
  \raggedright
  #2 % author name 
  \\[0.5ex]
  {
   \small\itshape
   \seq_item:Nn \g_bpclass_affiliation_seq { #1 } % affiliation
   \\
  }
  {
   \ttfamily\small
   \seq_item:Nn \g_bpclass_email_seq { #1 } % email
   \\
  }
  \bigskip
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\author{John Smith}
\email{john.smith@domain.tld}
\affiliation{University of Somewhere}

\author{Jane Smith}
\email{jane.smith@domain.tld}
\affiliation{University of Elsewhere}

\author{George Hastings}
\email{george.hastings@something.net}
\affiliation{University of Duckistan, Department of Duckology, and 
University of Another Place, Department of Long Names with No Meaning}

\printauthors

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `LaTeX3` solution :-) I always find such code with these new macros incredibly difficult to read, but of course that’s largely due to my inexperience.

Comment: I have two more questions about this: (A) I actually have three pieces of information for each author, I just wanted to simplify the example. But with `\seq_mapthread_function` I can only map two sequences. Is there an elegant way to do map/thread several seqs? (B) If I were to use this `expl3` code in my class would I be recommended to replace all ‘classic’ macros (such as `\newcommand`) with `expl3` ones?

Comment: @bp99 I feared that: the institution is obviously a necessary identification item. As I said, this is a skeleton, but without enough information on the intended usage, that's as much as I can do. You can map as many sequences as you want by taking one for indexing; check for `\seq_map_indexed_function:NN`

Comment: Thank you for your update. It’s hard to decide between the ‘new’ `expl3` based solution and the classic approach provided by others :-) By the way—not that it matters—, the third field I needed was a student ID, not affiliation. Mr. Hastings’s line made me chuckle though, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

Oh this is more or less the same as campa just posted:-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@author{\@gobble}
\def\author#1{\g@addto@macro\@author{\\#1&}}
\def\email#1{\g@addto@macro\@author{ \texttt{<#1>}}}
\def\maketitle{{%
\par
\Large\noindent\textbf{\@title}\par
\smallskip
\large
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}% allow  more than one email
\@author{}%
\end{tabular}
\par
\bigskip}}
\makeatother

\title{Example}
\author{John Smith}
\email{js@example.com}
\email{j.smith999@example.org}
\author{Jane Smith}
\email{jane@example.com}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Intro}
\vdots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oooh, the `\def\@author{\@gobble}` trick is also interesting.

Comment: @campa but you reminded me to put a `{}` guard in so it doesn't gobble the `\end` of `\end{tabular}` in the no-author case...